# some issue with sending numpy arrays over socket

Tags: python, numpy, sockets

I want to create a web server that will stream live webcam video from connected user(singular).

Currently im trying to send video frames coming from webcam over socket but having a strange issue. **The client stops sending frames after like 0.1 secs.**

Here is the output from server.py and its full output. Client stops sending frames as i said.

```
connection established with  ('127.0.0.1', 63585)
[[[138 157 155]
  [142 160 158]
  [145 161 157]
  ...
  [ 60  67  94]
  [ 57  64  90]
  [ 67  75  99]]

 [[144 160 159]
  [144 160 157]
  [145 160 156]
  ...
  [ 67  73  99]
  [ 63  70  94]
  [ 71  78 101]]
  [ 14  20  29]
  [ 13  21  28]
  ...
  [ 25  35  36]
  [ 23  33  34]
  [ 22  32  32]]

 [[ 15  19  28]
  [ 15  20  29]
  [ 15  21  28]
  ...
  [ 22  33  34]
  [ 22  33  33]
  [ 21  32  32]]

 [[ 16  19  28]
  [ 16  20  29]
  [ 16  21  29]
  ...
  [ 20  33  32]
  [ 20  33  32]
  [ 20  33  32]]]
```

I created 2 python files: server.py and client.py

**server.py**

```
import cv2
import pickle
import socket
import struct

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 9501

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # establishing a tcp connection
sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.listen(5)

data = b''
payload_size = struct.calcsize("I")

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = sock.accept() # wait for client
    print('connection established with ' ,client_address)    
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += client_socket.recv(4096)
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("I", packed_msg_size)[0]
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += client_socket.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]
    if frame_data=='':
        break
    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
    print(frame)
socket.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import cv2
import pickle
import socket
import struct

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 9501
server_address = (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)


streamer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
streamer.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))


while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    pos_frame = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    while True:
        flag, frame = cap.read()
        if flag:
            frame = pickle.dumps(frame)
            size = len(frame)
            p = struct.pack('I', size)
            frame = p + frame
            streamer.sendall(frame)
        else:
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos_frame-1)
      
        if cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
            size = 10
            p = struct.pack("I", size)
            streamer.send(p)
            streamer.send('')
            break
    streamer.close()
```

Comment: Can you try putting this line outside the server.py while loop?  "client_socket, client_address = sock.accept()"

Comment: There's no real need to pickle the frame to send it, since sockets can transport arbitrary binary data. You could consider just using `np.tobytes()` and sending that, along with image dimensions packed into the start of the transmission. Just a thought. It may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

@malcom32 posted this worked.  I'm posting the answer here for completeness.

Since you only need to set up the socket once, you can put this line outside the server.py while loop.

```
client_socket, client_address = sock.accept()
while True:
    print('connection established with ' ,client_address)
    ...
```